# How to uninstall Oracle JDK in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: jdk

I installed Oracle JDK on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

But I tried various suggestions from the forums and that didn't solve the issue. I purged the ppa and did an update also but it wouldn't remove.

Comment: Duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/q/433668/18665

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To remove **Oracle JDK** completely, run the commands given below(one-by-one) from terminal :-

- Check which JDK packages are installed

  `sudo dpkg --list | grep -i jdk`
- Remove Oracle Java 8 completely

  ```
  sudo apt-get purge oracle-java8-installer
  sudo apt-get autoremove
  ```
- Check that all JDK packages have been removed

  `sudo dpkg --list | grep -i jdk`

Then if you want to, you can also purge the PPA.

Comment: Are you sure this removes the files from /usr/lib/jvm/jdk? [Because I don't think it does](https://askubuntu.com/a/911267/18665). Also, `purge` will also uninstall, so you don't need to use `remove` first. See `man apt-get | grep purge`

Comment: I have edited my answer. I think Oracle JDK is removed completely after following the steps given in the answer. If you don't think so, please provide an appropriate solution.

Comment: If I put `apt remove oracle-java8-jdk`, I get `The following new packages will be installed: oracle-java7-jdk`. But I do not want Java 7. `oracle-java8-installer` is not available.

Comment: Why does it install another version of Java?